# Django jMeter Api testing fail due to http timeout connection fail

Tags: django, jmeter

Jmeter config:

webserver:

server name: 120.0.0.1

port no: 9000

Timeouts

Connect: Blank

Response: Blank

Method: GET

Thread user: 500

Ramp-up: 1

loop count: 1 (check box not checked)

In 500 user 70 user fail

here is code

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def country_list(request):
    #country = cache.get('country')

    try: 
        countryData = Country.objects.values('country_id','country_name').all().order_by('country_name')
        #countryData = Country.objects.extra(select={'name': 'country_name','id':'country_id'}).values('id','name').all().order_by('country_name')[:5] 
        serializer = CountrySerializer(countryData,many=True)
        #cache.set('country', serializer.data, 30)
        return JsonResponse({'data': serializer.data, 'error': 0 })
    except (KeyError, Country.DoesNotExist):
        return JsonResponse({ 'error': 1 })
```

and response is here

```
Thread Name: country 1-169
Sample Start: 2017-05-26 15:43:44 IST
Load time: 21014
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 2015
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 2015
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you found the bottleneck in your application. However it is hard to say what is the maximum amount of users which can be served providing reasonable response time and when the error start occurring.

I would recommend the following amendments:

1. Make sure you run JMeter and Django application on different hosts (JMeter is quite resource intensive and this way you will avoid mutual interference)
2. Change `Ramp-up` to something above 1 second (i.e. let it be 500 seconds so JMeter will add a user each second). The idea is to increase the load **gradually** this way you will be able to correlate increasing response time with the increasing load and will be able to exactly determine saturation and failure points. See [JMeter Ramp-Up - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide) for more details.
3. Change `Loop Count` to `-1` so your requests would loop forever
4. Set desired test duration in the "Scheduler" section of the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
5. Monitor OS resources consumption on Django server level using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/).

So when failure occurs you should know at least the following:

- how many concurrent users were there when it happened (you can view it using [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener or [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html))
- whether the failure is caused by lack of i.e. CPU or RAM. If not - further steps would be examining your backend configuration (i.e. whether web/database server configuration is suitable for that many connections, checking logs for any suspicious entries, using [Python Profiling Tools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to get the reason of slowness or failure, etc)